# WildCard in Java for classes that inherit from same class

Tags: java

Having the next classes in Java:

```
class A {
}
class B extends A {
}
class C extends A {
}

class ClassMethods {
    A method1(ArrayList<? extends A> list) {
        return list.get(1);
    }
    void method2(ArrayList<?> list, A el) {
        list.add(el);
    }

    void method3(A elem) {
        ArrayList<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
        listA.add(new A()); listA.add(new A());
        ArrayList<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
        listA.add(new B()); listB.add(new B());
        ArrayList<C> listC = new ArrayList<C>();
        listC.add(new C()); listC.add(new C());

        this.method1(listA);
        this.method1(listB);
        this.method1(listC);

        this.method2(listA, elem);
        this.method2(listB, elem);
        this.method2(listC, elem);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make `method2` working? Without overloading it. Because we write in the list, we may need a "? super x" specifier. But "super B" will not work for a C class for example. So I think the only possibility to make it work is to have one with "? super B" and an overload with "? super C". I can change only the "<...>" part of it, this is how the problem was proposed, and to explain if it can not be done.

Comment: I think you're jumping to the solution without understanding the problem.  The problem is that the compiler needs to know that `list` can accept **any** element of type `A`.  `? super A` is what you're looking for.  This means "`A` or any class that `A` extends".  This way, if someone passes in a list of `Object`s, the method will accept it, because all `A`s are `Object`s, but it will reject a list of `B`s, because not all `A`s are `B`s.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `A` was `Object` and `B` was `String`, would you expect to be able to take a `List<String> strs`, `Object item` and call `strs.add(item)`?

The closest thing you could do is dd a type parameter.

```
<T> void method2(ArrayList<? super T> list, T el) {
    list.add(el);
}
```

but that is the wrong way around.

If you try to inline `method2` you will see the error more directly.

```
    listA.add(elem);
    listB.add(elem); // No chance.
    listC.add(elem); // No chance.
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense.

Comment: The method should not accept a type parameter.  The method is supposed to accept an arraylist and an instance of `A`.  If you read the question, `A` is not a type parameter, it's a class name.  And the OP is only supposed to change the `list` parameter type, nothing else, so you haven't really answered the question.  Simply `ArrayList<? super A>` with no type parameter will do the trick.

Comment: <? super A> works in the method, but will bring an error in method3 here:  this.method2(listB, elem);
this.method2(listC, elem);